# stream a file over php

Tags: php, youtube

I have an flv file, and I would like to stream it over php, atm I have the following code :

**UPDATED CODE**
this is the code I copied from phihag, but now the code doesnt download the file, it returns and empty file!

`$file = $_GET['url'];

if ((substr($file, 0, 7) != 'http://') && (substr($file, 0, 8) != 'https://')) {

  die('You have to specify an HTTP URL');

}

$f = fopen($file, "rb"); // b is required on Windows

if ($f !== false) {

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');

    header('Content-Type: application/flv');

    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));

    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');

    header('Expires: 0');

    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');

    header('Pragma: public');

    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));

    ob_clean();

    flush();

    $f = fopen($_GET['file'], "r");

    while(!feof($f)) {

    echo fread($f,8192);

    }

    fclose($f);

    exit;

    }`

the code above doesnt work, for some reason it doesnt get passed the if statement, and when I remove the ifstatement it downloads an empty file!!! note that the file is stored on a remote server that I have no access to.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if (fopen($url, "r")) {` uses a variable `$url` which is not defined in this program. You probably want:

```
$file = $_GET['url'];
// Security check to prevent users from echoing all the files on this server
if ((substr($file, 0, 7) != 'http://') && (substr($file, 0, 8) != 'https://')) {
  die('You have to specify an HTTP URL');
}
$f = fopen($file, "rb"); // b is required on Windows
if ($f !== false) {
  header(...)
  echo ...
}
```

Comment: thanks but now its not rly downloading the file, its returning an empty file~!!

Comment: @ahoura `fopen` should be called just once in the whole code excerpt, remove the latter occurence. Also, make sure you can download the file in the first place.

Comment: hey, I am sure I can download the file because I did it manually, but I dont understand what you mean by remove the latter occurence...

Comment: @ahoura You got two `fopen`s in your code. Remove the line `$f = fopen($_GET['file'], "r");`. Also, being able to manually and automatically download the file is not the same; the content can depend on User-Agent, cookies, etc., and your php installation can be limited (for example, by <a href="http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen">`allow_url_fopen`</a>).

Answer (score 4):

Your server is probably [configured to disallow `fopen()` on URLs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen).

Also, you have an open proxy, which is a security risk.  You should be validating the URL requested, rather than passing who-knows-what through your server.  Worse yet, is that it is possible to pass a local file into `$_GET['file']` and rip off any file on your server accessible by the user that PHP runs as.  Scary stuff!